# $x_1, x_2,..., x_p$ are consecutive numbers, then at least one of them is divisible by $p$

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $p$ be a prime number, and let $x_1, x_2,..., x_p$ be natural numbers.
Consider the statement

If $x_1, x_2,..., x_p$ are consecutive numbers, then at least one of them is divisible
by $p$

I think that this statement is true since we have that we will go up to some $p$ (prime) of our sequence so this means that the $x_p$ natural number will always be divisible by $p$. How would I write this more symbolically since I have the idea in my head of what we want to prove.

Comment: By the way, the statement is true for any $n$.... not just primes.

Comment: It isn’t at all clear what your idea is. It is certainly not necessarily true that $x_p$ is divisible by $p$: if $p=3$, for instance, the numbers might be $x_1=3$, $x_2=4$, and $x_3=5$. In fact the statement is true even if $p$ is not prime. Do you know anything about modular arithmetic? Alternatively, you could consider the remainders when the numbers $x_i$ are divided by $p$.

Comment: No no no.  If I have $n= 128$ consecutive integers, *one* of them must be divisible by $128$.  See?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set $\{ r_i = x_i \mod p \}$.  How many elements does it have?  Use the pigeonhole principle to see that one of the $r_i$ must be $0$.

Comment: Probably the cleanest approach.

Answer (score 0):

Note: in writing this answer I have not assumed that the asker knows about modular arithmetic, though the proof is the same albeit longer.

Let $x_1=ap+r$ for $a\ge 0$ and $0\le r<p$. This is possible by the division algorithm. Then $x_k=ap+r+(k-1)$ for $1\le k \le p$. If $r=0$, we are done because then $x_1=ap$ and hence $p\mid x_1$. If not, $1\le r \le p-1$ so that
$$ 1\le p-r\le p-1.$$
So, setting $m-1=p-r$ we have $2\le m \le p$. So,
$$ x_m=ap+r+(m-1)=ap+r+(p-r)=(a+1)p$$
and $p\mid x_m$.